# Imported KML does not show formatted description in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

I created two KML files by copying and pasting their content directly from [Google Manual](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#using-the-cdata-element). One file it the first example (using CDATA), another one is the second (without CDATA). I then created a new [custom Google Map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zPGVs3lO8HyY.kjKU9DIsvZkE) and added two layers importing both KML files.

The problem is that I cannot make formatting work. There are no red, italic, or bold fonts on the description as they should be according to both KML files.

That is how I can see the description in both Chrome and IE, on two different computers (Windows 10 64 and Windows 7 64):

[image]

Any ideas why I cannot see formats and how to make them work?

Comment: Look at the KML in your MyMap (export it), the formatting has been stripped.

Comment: @geocodezip, thanks, but I did not do anything to strip the formatting. I just clicked "Add layer" and "Import KML". Any ideas which settings and where could have done that?

Comment: MyMaps seems to strip the formatting out.

Comment: If you have a webserver to serve your KML, KmlLayer renders it with the formatting in the infowindows: [green](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160307_GoogleEx2_Trial.kml), [red](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160307_GoogleEx2_Trial.kml)

Answer (score 1):

I think Google Earth supports HTML tags, but Google custom map (old name : my map) does not support HTML tags currently. KML file is just a data file. Supporting all features of KML format, or not is depends on the application.

[image]

[image]